# Velocity adjustment calculation

Tags: math, vector, velocity, game-physics, game-ai

I'm developing an Android 2D "space fighters" game, and I am now developing the AI.

The AI (enemy) is moving at a certain velocity V1 (V1x, V1y), and it wants to adjust this velocity so that it matches the intercept vector at max speed.

I know that the intercept velocity is achievable as:

```
V_intercept = (player.x - enemy.x, player.y - enemy.y)
normalize(V_intercept)
V_intercept.x *= MAX_SPEED
V_intercept.y *= MAX_SPEED
```

What I'm looking for is a way to find a single velocity `v_correction`, which, when applied for `t` time, will put the enemy in the correct velocity towards the player.

I suppose I'm looking for 2 functions:

```
getCorrectionVelocity(current_velocity, desired_velocity, acceleration) // not sure if acceleration is even needed here

getTimeToReachVelocity(current_velocity, desired_velocity, acceleration)
```

Note:

Mass & steering time are not relevant. Imagine all mass = 1, and time to turn to a certain direction = 0

Also, I will need these methods in other parts of the AI (for instance, to calculate how much time it will take for the enemy to match its velocity with the player's velocity), and so I need them to be generic, meaning be able to calculate the correction & time to any velocity I give them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, would you not restrict the acceleration too? And probably also the jerk. So no direction change in zero time. Second, any intelligent artifical intelligence would measure the motion of the target, predict it via linear continuation and head to a realistic intercept point. Your method only works efficiently when the target is stationary. If the target is not stationary, then the hunter will follow a very curved path, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit_curve.

Answer (score 0):

I do it differently. Forget about computing exact correction impulse per time instead just control steer

[image: AI steer]

So compute `dot_product(AI_velocity,delta)` and according to sign of it steer left or right (direction depends on your coordinate system). So for intercepting apply continuously main thrust and also some minor steer thrust.

But you have to implement Newtonian D'Alembert physics something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19241804/2521214).

If you want to apply frictions also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20017455/2521214)